# How do I get sum of number digits in a list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a program that returns sum of number digits in a list using nested for loop.

```
numlist = [12,34,56,78,90]
out = []
for x in numlist:
    t = 0
    for y in str(x):
        t += int(y)
    out.append(t)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[3,7,11,15,9]
```

But, I would like to the same using list comprehension.

```
res = [t := t+int(y) for x in numlist for y in str(x)]
print(res)
```

But, it doesn't return what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After converting int to char list, you can convert them to int with `map`, then `sum` the int list:

```py
res = [sum(map(int, str(x))) for x in numlist]
```

```
print(res)

[3, 7, 11, 15, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested list comp:

```
[sum([int(char) for char in str(x)]) for x in numlist]
```